# How to authorize a WebApi endpoint to be consumed only for one specific user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I  need to install an asp.net web api service on an onpremises IIS where there is an active directory.

I found this link:
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/integrated-windows-authentication

but its not clear how to authorize this service to be used only for one specific user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your configuration is correctly set up for utilizing Windows auth, then you should be able to decorate the controller class or one specific action method with the following to achieve what you want:

`[Authorize(Users="MyOneAuthorizedUser")]`

Comment: Will this work also if the service is hosted on Windows Azure with Windows Azure authentication?